# Перемещать блок с помощью событий клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать управление блоком по сайту с помощью стрелок.
Для стрелок влево и вправо работает а для вверх и вниз нет.

```js
var div_c = document.getElementById("block");
window.addEventListener('keydown', f, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', f, false);
var left = 0;
var top = 0;

function f(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      top -= 10;
      div_c.style.top = top + 'px';
      break;
    case 40:
      top += 10;
      div_c.style.top = top + 'px';
      break;
    case 39:
      left += 10;
      div_c.style.left = left + 'px';
      break;
    case 37:
      left -= 10;
      div_c.style.left = left + 'px';
      break;

  }
}
```

```css
#block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="block"></div>
  <script src="tuhes.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема связанна с областью видимости переменных в JS. Если вывести console.log, то можно увидеть, что там объект window.top, а не ваша переменная.

```
case 38:
      top -= 10;
      console.log(top);
      div_c.style.top = top + 'px';
      break;
```

Самое простое решение: изменить название переменной.